# How to use profiling in Goland IDE

Tags: profiling, jetbrains-ide, goland

I press `Run` button  to start my program work then I press button `Start CPU Usage Profiling`. At the end I get a file like `GO-version_username_time.zip`.

What should I do next? How can I get a list of most expensive functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update:

As of GoLand 2019.1, it is possible to profile Go applications or Go tests. See [this article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2019/04/03/profiling-go-applications-and-tests/) for more information on how to do this.

Old post:

Currently, the IDE does not have any Go profiling support. You can watch/vote for [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4162) for when profiling will be integrated into the IDE.

The functionality you've mentioned, `Start CPU Usage Profiling`, relates to profiling the IDE itself, in case performance problems occur and need to be reported to the developers.

Comment: If you have written benchmarks, it might be possible to configure the test command to generate a profile that you could then read use pprof. Haven't figured it out yet, I'll update if I do. If anyone has had luck with this, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You can follow the instructions here to use the profiling tools, https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs However, the IDE currently does not have any special support for this.

Comment: I've found that if you want your benchmarks to automatically generate profiles, you can add `-test.cpuprofile cpu.pprof` to the "Program Arguments" field in the test command configuration modal.